# Leaks in celery task on exception

Tags: python, django

Recently I realized that at some point celery starts consuming a lot of memory and in the end django throws DB error.

Celery tasks contain some manipulations with django models and other logic. I started investigating the problem and I saw quite good correlation between memory usage growth and a number of unhandled exceptions in one task.

So it seems that if I perform some action on db and then an exception is raised inside a task the DB connection it opened for populating model with data hangs and never gets freed. So in the end memory usage growth so finally I get `FATAL:  sorry, too many clients already` inside a psycopg driver.

Is it true and this works like that? If so can I release DB connection in case of exception? Sure enough I can `except` this exception and print some error message, but I guess there are some tasks either a task returns a correct value or it should raise an exception to terminate a `group` or something so we can't just suppress exception.

Comment: How are you getting a DB connection inside the celery task? Is it with a context manager (which then you'd expect to clean up) or some other way (that you'd maybe expect to need to manually tear down in case of exception)? Can you show your [task and related] code?

Comment: @Tom Dalton, well as I said I just use Django models. `f = someapp.models.Foo.objects.get(pk=pk)` and so on. There is no explicit place I personally open a connection. It's up to Django's ORM and I have no idea how does it work under the hood.